Inverse Kinematics on *not* chained Bones
Is it possible to add IK on an Armature, that has partly no chained Bones, as you can see with the leg in the reference? If you go from down the foot, all the way to the upper leg, it is a chain of child parent relationships, as it is more intuitive for me to animate them from a horizontal perspective.
However, I don't know how to add IK for something like this. I've tried to extrude a Bone from the Foot naming it "LegControl" and I've also created a Bone that is on the same height as the Knee, naming it "KneeIK". Then, I've added the IK constraint to the FootBone and set it like this:
Target: Armature
Bone: KneeIK
Pole Target: Armature
Bone: LegControl
It produces unwanted results. Is there a way to use IK here, or is it only possible for when bones are chained together?

In my example Hips, top, mid and bot bones are yours original bones, in a parent-child relationship as FK chain.
I added top Ik, mid IK, bot IK, thigh and shin bones.

Thigh is child of hips, top IK is child of thigh, mid IK is child of shin, bot IK is child of Root bone (nothing in my example).
Shin has an IK constraint, targeting bot IK, lenght of 2, so bot IK is the bone to use when animating in IK.
Top, mid and bot have a copy transform constraint targeting their respective siblings.
I also added a custom property to drive the Influence of all the 3 Copy Transform constraints, so to act as FK/IK Slider.
When the animation is done, you can select Top, Mid and bot, go to pose menu > Animation > Bake action (visual keying, delete constraints, overwrite current), so to have the animation acting completely on the FK chain, free from any constraint.

it works, thank you very much :)
